# Proxy causes that two clients see the same output

Tags: php, apache, yii, proxy

Yesterday I made the test of my online game on the campus. Everything was fine, but there were  a few wired errors: More then one users saw the same output, which should be different for each of them. Reloading the site was fixing this error. I think that it is connected with proxy we have to use on campus, however I have to fix it. How can I do this?
Server configuration: apache, php, yii

```
    <ifModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "now plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "now plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "now plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType text/css "now plus 1 months"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 days"
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes                   
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the proxy not to cache your page.

Caching Tutorial for Web Authors and Webmasters:

http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#CACHE-CONTROL

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>
```

Example code from: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Also note the warning at the top of that man-page:

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, ...

"any actual output" includes blanks and blank lines.

Comment: I am not good with apache things :) I added my current cache and gzip conf. Can you suggest have can I change it?

Comment: ohh, if I use https (which I implemented) proxy won't cache it :) quick fix ;) But how can I do this without SSL?

Comment: But this disable caching at all :{ Isn't possible to disable only proxy caching in .htaccess?

Comment: @RobM The example PHP code disables caching only for the particular page.  I do not understand what you mean by "disable caching at all". If you have a "one-page app", then you may need to wrap the example code in a conditional statement.  Yes you could control the cache with .htaccess.  You need to disable caching for any output which only a particular user should see.  This can be accomplished with PHP. You might want to consider session handling:  http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php

Comment: @RobM now i get it, you want the browser to cache but not the proxy.  I think you need to go with sessions and session handling.

Comment: Exactly, cache for non-proxy users should remains as it is, but for proxy users I want to disable caching.

Comment: @RobM One cannot give the proxy cache a separate directive from the browser cache, afaik.